# Train tickets for tourists in Norway from Oslo to Bergen

Tags: trains, oslo, bergen

We are a group of Chinese friends traveling to Schengen countries in March and April. Our last stop is Bergen, Norway and from there we will fly to London Gatwick.

We understand that Oslo to Bergen is supposed to be a scenic train journey and our plan is to buy train tickets for 19 April 2017. We are not planning to stop at Flåm, but would like to be able to go through Flåm on our way to Bergen.
We have been looking for prices on [Rail Europe](http://www.raileurope-world.com/spip.php?page=sales&re_domain=ptp&re_oper=results&cmpid=PSN020401) but it shows 109 euros for every date.

Are the prices always the same for trains in Norway from Oslo to Bergen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do train prices in Norway increase close to date of travel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71873/do-train-prices-in-norway-increase-close-to-date-of-travel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are prices always the same for trains in Norway from Oslo to Bergen?
>   our travel date is 19 April 2017

If you have a definite plan for a certain date there are lowest price train fares available which can be bought in advance from an official [NSB](https://www.nsb.no/en/frontpage) website. This is one of the scenic train journeys in Europe and lowest price train tickets have limited seats, therefore you can buy these lowest train tickets in advance if you a definite plan for 19 April 2017. Further the price is 249 NOK (28 Euros) which is considerably cheaper. The only concern is these lowest price train tickets are non-refundable, otherwise standard price 913 NOK (104 Euros) would always be available.

Source:[NSB](https://www.nsb.no/en/booking/select-trip?to=Bergen&from=Oslo+S&departureDatetime=2017-04-19%2003:00&departureSearchForArrival=false&returnSearchForArrival=false&petFree=false&passengers=1&noStairs=false&passengerType1=1&bookingPassengerCategorySpecial_11=0&toStation=2351000&fromStation=100000&turnOnly=false&selectedIndexOut=0l)

[image: Oslo to Bergen timetable extract]

> We are not planning to stop at Flåm, but would be able to pass Flåm on
>   our way to Bergen?

No, you will not be able to see Flåm on your way to Bergen. You will need to change trains at Myrdal and take another train [Flåm Railway](https://www.visitflam.com/en/se-og-gjore/se/flamsbana-the-flam-railway/) if your are planning to visit Flåm.

The following is the map and stops of train from Oslo to Bergen:

[image: map and stops of train from Oslo to Bergen]

Comment: Full-fare tickets are not always available. Most long-distance trains in Norway operate with a mandatory seat reservation and if the train is full, the train is simply full and you will not get a ticket at all.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo of course,  that depends on availability

Comment: Then you should perhaps correct your answer saying: 'standard price 913 NOK (104 Euros) would always be available'.